# How to find all changes below a certain point in the TFS source control tree

Tags: tfs

I need to know what changes (if any) have happened at a particular level in our source control tree. Is there some way to make such a query of TFS?

Comment: do you want to do this programatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Using Team Explorer:**

1. Open Source Control Explorer
2. Navigate to desired source control folder
3. Right-click and choose View History

Shows you all of the changesets that have been checked in at that level in the tree or below.



**Using the tf utility:**

`tf history c:\localFolder -r -format:detailed`

Here's a link to the tf history documentation for more details on usage: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx)



**Using the [TFS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130334.aspx) to do it programatically:**

Here's a sample method based on some of our code. It takes a path, start time and end time and gives you all of the changeset details below that path in between the two specified times:

```cs
private StringBuilder GetTfsModifications(string tfsPath, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    StringBuilder bodyContent = new StringBuilder();

    TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("YourServerNameHere");
    VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

    // Get collection of changesets below the given path
    System.Collections.IEnumerable changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(
            tfsPath, 
            VersionSpec.Latest, 
            0, 
            RecursionType.Full, 
            null, 
            new DateVersionSpec(startTime), 
            new DateVersionSpec(endTime), 
            int.MaxValue, 
            true, 
            false);

    // Iterate through changesets and extract any data you want from them
    foreach (Changeset changeset in changesets)
    {
        StringBuilder changes = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder assocWorkItems = new StringBuilder();

        // Create a list of the associated work items for the ChangeSet
        foreach (WorkItem assocWorkItem in changeset.WorkItems)
        {
            assocWorkItems.Append(assocWorkItem.Id.ToString());
        }

        // Get details from each of the changes in the changeset
        foreach (Change change in changeset.Changes)
        {
            changes.AppendLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "\t{0}\t{1}", 
                    PendingChange.GetLocalizedStringForChangeType(change.ChangeType), 
                    change.Item.ServerItem));
        }

        // Get some details from the changeset and append the individual change details below it
        if (changes.Length > 0)
        {
            bodyContent.AppendLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", 
                    changeset.ChangesetId, 
                    changeset.Committer.Substring(changeset.Committer.IndexOf('\\') + 1), 
                    changeset.CreationDate, 
                    changeset.Comment, 
                    assocWorkItems.ToString()));
            bodyContent.Append(changes.ToString());
        }
    }

    return bodyContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the answer could be as simple as:

```
tf history c:\some\subdir -r -format:detailed -noprompt
```

Reply if that's not good enough.